# Access array key from return value

Tags: php, arrays

If I have a function that returns an array, how can I access a key from it directly from the function call?

Example:

```
function foo() {
    return array('a' => 1);
}

foo()['a']; //no good
```

Comment: from php 5.4 up this `foo()[1]` is valid syntax. ide's such as dreamweaver won't recognize it as such though and will throw big red lines. but it definitely is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it directly like that in versions < 5.4. You need to store the return value of `foo()` somewhere:

```
function foo() {
    return array('a' => 1);
}

$bar = foo();

echo $bar['a'];
```

In PHP 5.4 and up, your code will work. [Demo](https://ideone.com/2XpEbP).

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Thanks for reminding me of the 5.4 part; I recalled a change in there somewhere, but forget when it was. :)

Comment: meh, thinking about it, my reaction was quite childish, you deserve this :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the function to a variable first - like this:

```
$bar = foo();
$bar['a'];
```

You have to actually call a function to get a return value - in this case you are trying to get an array value from something which is not an array.

Note, this is true only for versions of PHP before 5.4.